# What are the options to customize scp.plot_multiple for Raman spectra analysis?

Tags: python, plot

**Using spectrochempy for raman analysis**

Hi, I'm new to using scp for raman and am really getting stuck. Right now, I read in the text file and make a plot through

```
A = scp.read_labspec("filename", directory = 'filepath') 
data = [A[0], A[1], A[2]] #three different spectra with same x axis (raman shift)
labels = ["spot {}".format(label) for label in ["1", "2", "3"]]
 _ = scp.plot_multiple(method = "pen", style = "sans", 
                     datasets = data, labels = labels, legend = "best", title = "Laser Test", 
                     xlim=(200.0, 1800.0), ylim=(0.0, 300.0))`
```

My problem is that I want a) all the lines of each spot to be solid (right now spot2 and spot3 are dotted), and b) I want to know the other possibilities for scp.plot_multiple for improving my plot. Can I change the colors of the spots for the legend? Can I change the color of the title? Stuff like that. Thank you in advance!

I've tried the 1D plot, but can't figure out how to "hold on" equivalent from matlab to python so I only get one figure. Open to trying other scp ideas.

Comment: What documentation / tutorial URL(s) are you relying on?

Comment: https://www.spectrochempy.fr/latest/userguide/reference/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of SpectroChemPy (scp),
I'm one of the developers of SpectroChemPy (scp).
I'm sorry I've only discovered this question now. It's because we usually use
GitHub to share about the program, but now I see there are also some questions on StackOverflow.

Perhaps the following link might help: https://github.com/spectrochempy/spectrochempy/discussions/689

Some features you ask for (plot_multiple option) were not implemented yet at the time of the question, but in the latest development you can find them :https://www.spectrochempy.fr/latest/reference/generated/spectrochempy.plot_multiple.html#spectrochempy.plot_multiple

(However, you have to install from Conda to use the dev version, see the docs for instructions on this) or if you use pip you have to wait a week or two for it to appear in the Stable version).

> I've tried 1D plotting, but I can't figure out how to "maintain" the matlab equivalent in python, so I only get one figure. I'm open to other scp ideas.

In the meantime, you can also plot the graph yourself using plot(),
successive plots on the same figure can be made using the `clear=False` keyword.

```
x.plot()
x2.plot(clear=False)
```

Without this option, you'll get separate figures.